# PDFKit: Fonts are getting blurred on windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit gem, to generate pdf file in a Ruby on Rails project.
File is being generated successfully and is view-able too. When I am opening the file **on windows XP machine the fonts are getting blurred**.
It is **looking good on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 7 machine**.

Please suggest me, what can be done in this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF illustrating the issue for analysis.

Comment: have you tried different pdf readers? Try Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader, Chrome (actually the same engine as Foxit Reader). Fonts antialiasing when viewing PDF is performed by the reader software and can't be really controlled from PDF.